# MongoDB : Aggregate and Match duplicated values in two fields

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the collection with the following data in in

```
 {_id: 1, a : 12345, b : [2,3]}, 
 {_id: 2, a : 666}, 
 {_id: 3, a : 6, b : [15, 20]},
 {_id: 4, a : 1111, b : [12345, 156]}
```

I need to match same values that are present in **a** and **b**. For the following data the aggregation should return **12345**.

I use the next code to get all values from b

```
 db.collection.aggregate([
        {$unwind: "$b"},
        {$project: {_id: "$b"}}
 ])
```

But stuck on what to do next and how to compare results with **a** field. 
Ty for your help.

Comment: Though solving this on your small sample is really quite  trivial ( though no correct answer as of writing ), the trivial solution is not likely to scale to a real world case. What  is your real world case to be solved here? How many possible values can be contained in both fields? And also does it really matter if the same value is recorded in another field in another document? It's hard to see the real world application of this, so it could do with some explanation.

Comment: Hi.. So my real word problem is something like this. I have profiles collection. Which have uniqueId of customer(Always the same). Sometimes we merge two profiles together, and those uniqueId comes into field caled B. Later when we want to check maybe we already had this profile merged. To make sure that his customerId not in B field. So we can save it as a new person or merge it if we already do this previously. Hope this helps

Comment: So if I catch your meaning correctly. Then "field B" contains what is "possibly" two values that came from "field A" and now you need to find those values where they are "duplicated" between the fields? That seems to be the ask, but am I missing something here? As if that is the case then why did not the original "field A" document get removed in the first place? Or is that the problem you are trying to "solve/fix" here? The biggest issue is "size". Here. What are we talking in total distinct values? Hundreds? Thousands? Millions? It all makes a difference to the scope of solution.

Comment: Yeah you get the point.. Document get's removed. We create field B because if we will need to update removed profile data(we already remove it), we need to update merged one who have his own uniqueId(field A). So that's why we create field B. To hold all customerIds(field A) that present in this profile(lets call it historyIds). Hope this helps.

Comment: So my logic on aggregation looks like this. Grab all values from field B, grab all values from field A. Compare to see duplicates. The only problem how to compare them

Comment: Okay. But like I said, the actual processing of this ( presumably one off operation to migrate and remove ) is all about the "scale" of what you potentially have right now as possible distinct values in combination. The aggregation is either "easy" ( small enough a result to fit the  16MB BSON limit per document, and I mean "one document" ), or it's a matter of "scale" to how much memory is available to a process and therefore mostly on how many possible distinct values can be generated. If the first case does not suit, then no single aggregate statement will ever do this.

Comment: The short shrift of the solution is to basically identify distinct values from "A" and then return the "matching" distinct values from "B". Implementation is a matter of "scale", naturally.